# Does Angular 2.0 Support Opera Mini

Tags: angular, opera-mini

Given this article:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/angular-2-0

Angular 2.0 will support Opera but does not mention Opera Mini. I suppose that means there will not be support but would like some confirmation before writing off what would otherwise be a wonderful framework for us.

Background: I'm developing for the East Africa region where Opera Mini can compose over 80% of traffic in some countries.

Comment: It will certainly not. 2.0 supports modern Opera versions, they are essentially the same as Chrome (Blink+V8) and have nothing in common with Opera Mini, except the name. Opera Mini lacks the features, I'm not sure if it is capable of running actual 1.x.

Comment: "East Africa region where Opera Mini can compose over 80% of traffic in some countries"- that's interesting to know, I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specs have been updated since that article (I think they now go down to IE9), but Opera Mini has really shoddy javascript support so using any client-side framework for it is a bad idea. They may work since they do have some support, but don't count on it.

In general, if 80% of your users are on opera mini, don't use a SPA. In fact, you may want to avoid javascript completely, using something like Django would be a much safer option and it would probably result in a smaller page for the user to download (and saving on data is one of the prime reasons people use Opera mini).

Answer (score 1):

Angular still doesn't have support for [proxy browsers](https://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-proxy-browser.htm) (Opera Mini, Uc Browser). Have tried server side rendering with Universal but to no avail. As suggested by [Erik Honn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746431/erik-honn), your best bet is going with a Server rendered app