# What are the poly-fills to be used to work Angular 10 in opera mini?

Tags: angular, opera-mini

Is there any poly-fills to be added to make angular 10 works in opera mini?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948658/does-angular-2-0-support-opera-mini

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of investigation, i found a solution. we can modify target to es5 in tsconfig.base.json because es6 will not work in opera mini.

### tsconfig.base.json

/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Modified one

/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

For reference, please go through below links

https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration
https://angular.io/cli/build